# Is MoCA better for home network if coax cable is all over the house already? Or just rewire whole house with ethernet?

Tags: data-wiring, wifi

House is full of coax cable.  Want to direct wire some devices with a switchbox and still have wifi.  Use moca and current wire or future proof like CAT7?

Comment: Only you can determine if it's worth it to use the current wire or to future proof. We have no idea (especially with the minimal details here) of your current wiring situation, the state of your walls, your budget, your DIY ability and willingness to work/learn, how much you're willing to pay to have someone do it for you... What is "better" is entirely up to you since there is little to no code around low-voltage communication wiring.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you don't have conduit for the network wires, use the wires you have until it hurts, and then face the pain of getting new wires in. If it never hurts enough for that, you get lucky.

If you have conduit, the game changes. Which is why some of us strongly suggest conduit for networking. But ripping the walls open for new wire when the wire you have works well enough for your actual use (as opposed to your theoretical not yet use) is pointless.

There is no "just rewire" without conduit, for any reasonable value of "just."